# Android-App using Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-android-sdk, facebook-permissions

in my android app I use the facebook graph api. I need specific permissions for "user_likes".

for example the request could look like this: me/likes?fields={anyField}

such a request works in facebook graph api explorer but not in my own app because I have no permissions. I have to fill out a form to get this permissions:

> Fill out the form below to submit your app for approval. You must
>   include usage information about your app for the review team. Your app
>   will be reviewed for compliance with our Platform Policy and Review
>   Guidelines.

my app is under construction, I would like to have something like a "sandbox mode" is such a thing available?

I hope you understand what i mean...i do not really know how to explain it precisely.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t need to get anything reviewed for testing, `user_likes` will work for everyone with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester), without the need to go through the review process.

If it does not work in your App, even as App Developer, you must have done something wrong in the login process: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/login-with-facebook/v2.2?locale=en_GB